# How to fix "missing required param: name" in graphql

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to generate a Stripe checkout session and working with Apollo Studio Explorer. Per directions, I've entered the query

```
query checkout($products: [ID]!) {
  checkout(products: $products) {
    session
  }
}
```

and the query variables

```
{
 "products": ["642362420f73e51550e9ff65",
    "642362420f73e51550e9ff66"]
}
```

After clicking Run in Apollo Studio Explorer's query panel, I get the following error message:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Missing required param: name.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "checkout"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "type": "StripeInvalidRequestError",
          "raw": {
            "code": "parameter_missing",
            "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
            "message": "Missing required param: name.",
            "param": "name",
            "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_Ec8s3XeWU5g7zB?t=1680042342",
            "type": "invalid_request_error",
```

I've looked over everything and I have followed the directions. I'm just not sure how to resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It seems the error message you received indicates that you are missing a required parameter called "name" in the request you are sending to Stripe. 
Doesn't looks like a GraphQL Issue but a server-side issue with calling the Stripe API to create the checkout session.

Comment: As @HasanPatel mentioned, this issue is related to the stripe API, not GraphQL nor Apollo. Could you link the URL of the API and the associated docs? I can only find the REST stripe api. A wild guess is that you have to add a "name" parameter to your query:  

```GraphQL
query checkout($products: [ID]!, $name: String!) {
  checkout(products: $products, name: $name) {
    session
  }
} 
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps [link] (https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes#parameter-missing), [link] (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions). I tried your wild guess @nohehf but it didn't work unfortunately. Thank!

Comment: The links you provided mention a REST API. I cannot really help without the GraphQL docs or at list endpoint URL